# how to disable copy for particular element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here, I'm having a problem with copy option when select 3 elements all the three are getting copied. But, I have a Jquery function to disable copy for the middle element. How I can disable that while selecting 3 elements. But, If I select the middle element individually it's not copying.

```js
$('#notcp').bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p >
select and copy
</p>
<p id="notcp">
cannot copy
</p>
<p>
select and copy
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use This CSS Style to disable Selection. By this The Text will not be selected. Thus can't be copied also.

```
#notcp {
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, No use. If I have 3 elements I want to disable copy for middle one. If I select only middle one it will work. If I select with 3 elements it won't work.

Comment: I ended up needing to hide the target elements so they wouldn't show up in a copied output.

Answer (score 1):

This feature can be done via *disabling* **Text Selection** using few **CSS** lines:

```
html, body {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try add  return false;

```html
   $('#notcp').bind('copy paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
$(document).on("cut copy paste","#notcp",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Try this <p  oncopy="return false" >cannot copy</p>

Comment: It will work only when we select particular element. If it select with other elements it is not working. see this https://jsfiddle.net/ZxKdp/227/